# selected value not appear in select option in html

Tags: javascript, html

I create option dynamically. I bind the all values but when I select value from dropdown menu it not display in the combo box.
help me how to fix this. thanks in advance

HTML:

```
  <select name= "cityNameOption"  id = "cityNameOption" >
    <option value="0">All</option></select>
```

js:

```
// cityList = [{"id":3,"name":"Hospitals"},{"id":1,"name":"Hotels"},{"id":2,"name":"Shopping Mall"}];


      var cityObject = jQuery.parseJSON(cityList);
        var cityOptions = document.getElementById("cityNameOption");


    for ( var i = 1; i <= cityObject.length; i++) {

        cityOptions.options[i] = new Option(cityObject[i - 1].name, cityObject[i - 1].id);
    }
```

Comment: It may be result of some javascript error elsewhere in the code, or some other code that listenes to `change` event on this select and cancels it or resets the value to default one. I don't see anything in example code you provided that could cause this kind of problem.

Comment: Just a minor nit; [HTML has no combo box](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/HtmlHasNoComboBox) :)

Comment: @ALL: Did you tested with jQuery mobile beta3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select name= "cityNameOption"  id = "cityNameOption" >
  <option value="0">All</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
  //warning 1: js-code must be after HTML
  //warning 2: JSON-object must be as a string;
  var cityList = '[{"id":3,"name":"Hospitals"},{"id":1,"name":"Hotels"},{"id":2,"name":"Shopping Mall"}]';
  var cityObject = $.parseJSON(cityList);
  for ( var i = 1; i <= cityObject.length; i++) {
    $("#cityNameOption").append('<option value='+cityObject[i - 1].id+'>'+cityObject[i - 1].name+'</option>');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm getting <option value=3>hospital</option> but when i select hospital, it not shown in combo box

Comment: @ALL: Did you tested with jQuery mobile beta3?